# postgreSQL syntax error at or near "foreign"

Tags: postgresql

I get the following error of "syntax error at or near "foreign"" when trying to create kurinys table. Might be a silly mistake but I can't recognize it. Thank you in advance.

```
create table elba7430.kurinys(
    id INTEGER not null check (id > 10000),
    pavadinimas VARCHAR (55) not null,
    metai YEAR,
    meno_rusies_id INTEGER not null check (meno_rusies_id > 100),
    autoriaus_id INTEGER not null check (autoriaus_id > 1000000),
    kliento_id INTEGER not null check (kliento_id > 1000000),
    ilgis_cm DECIMAL (100,2),
    plotis_cm DECIMAL (100,2),
    kaina DECIMAL (100,2),
    primary key (id),
    foreign key (meno_rusies_id) 
        REFERENCES elba7430.meno_rusis on delete cascade on update restrict,
    foreign key (autoriaus_id) 
        REFERENCES elba7430.autorius on delete cascade on update restrict,
    foreign key (kliento_id)
        REFERENCES elba7430.klientas on delete cascade on update restrict
);


create table elba7430.meno_rusis(
        id INTEGER not null check (id > 100),
        pavadinimas VARCHAR (100) not null,
        primary key(id)
);

create table elba7430.autorius(
    id INTEGER not null check (id > 1000000),
    vardas VARCHAR (40) not null,
    pavarde VARCHAR (55) not null,
    gimimo_metai DATE,
    primary key(id)
);

create table elba7430.klientas(
    id INTEGER not null check (id > 1000000),
    vardas VARCHAR (40),
    pavarde VARCHAR (55),
    primary key(id)
);
```

Comment: You need to create the tables you are referencing **before** the tables that reference them.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I already did it, still getting the error.

Comment: `year` isn't a data type. `metai YEAR` should probably be `metai integer`. Then it works: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=ebc3284142599be908fa61e6fe8c3312

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name still getting the same error

Comment: Then the code you are showing us, is not the code you are running. Because with those changes it does work: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=2b1aba110843c90859f7aad5681d8ef5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the order of your declarations and replacing the year data type by a valid one will solve this issue, here you can replicate this: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=d8fcb531295ecfddd6e20b0fb961c848)